# x axis label word wrap in high charts for radar chart

Tags: charts, highcharts

Im trying to adjust the X axis label for Radar chart in highchart and I couldnt fix the 2 labels. when its on small width screen,some labels are not seen completely. attached the screenshot
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI2KN.jpg)

Here is the fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/xs9zb3f6/6/`enter code here`

can someone help please? I want either the labels to be aligned further inside radar chart or word wrap so that when its on small screen it does not cut the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own function to move labels.

Get bbox of the label element and check if it is inside the container (>= 0 or <= container's width). One caveat in getting bbox - the labels are rotated, so it means that the bbox you get has params of the element which is not rotated yet - in your case when the rotation does not change text width a lot - you can add some pixels to offset that difference.

```
function moveLabels() {
  const ticks = this.xAxis[0].ticks;
  const safeDistance = 10;

  Object.keys(ticks).forEach(value => {
    const label = ticks[value].label;
    const bbox = label.getBBox(true);

    if (bbox.y >= 0) {
      if (bbox.x - safeDistance < 0) {
        label.attr({
          x: label.xy.x + Math.abs(bbox.x - safeDistance)
        })
      } else if (bbox.x + bbox.width + safeDistance > this.chartWidth) {
        label.attr({
          x: label.xy.x - (bbox.x + bbox.width + safeDistance - this.chartWidth)
        });
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Move labels on load/redraw events:

```
  chart: {
 polar: true,
    type: 'line',
    events: {
      load: moveLabels,
      redraw: moveLabels
    }
  },
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/nd5fob5d/